# Add images in popup feature of ol-ext (OpenLayers)

Tags: javascript, image, popup, openlayers

I am trying to add images within the popup feature of ol-ext (OpenLayers) available at https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext/blob/master/examples/popup/map.popup.feature.html

Any workarounds on how to either add images below the popup or within it? I have already asked for it to be added as a feature at the official repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are displaying data in an HTML table so to display an image you would need the necessary HTML to construct an image - in the case of the example you could show the department flag by using its id in the url for the image src.  The source I am using has flags for most, but not all, French departments

```
      'id': {
        title: 'Flag',  // attribute's title
        before: '<img src="https://www.crwflags.com/fotw/images/f/fr-',
        after: '.gif">'
       }
```

Comment: So simple!! Thank you for your answer!!